# Webdriver: IE11: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Software caused connection abort: recv failed

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

While running my test scripts in win7 IE11 using Selenium WebDriver I am getting below error:

```
Error:
==============================================================================================
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)
2.42.0.0

Listening on port 13127

org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute

INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Software 
caused connection abort: recv failed

org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute

INFO: Retrying request

JavaScript error (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 169 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a', time: '2014-03-27 17:17:32'
System info: host: 'blr2261913', ip: '10.177.101.114', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
Session ID: 71972154-3b97-4623-b651-aaa0bb460ffb
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, javascriptEnabled=true, elementScrollBehavior=0, ignoreZoomSetting=false, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=f
r=dismiss, version=11, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, requireWindowFocus=false, handlesAlerts=true,
e, browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, takesScreenshot=true}]
com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: JavaScript error (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 169 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a', time: '2014-03-27 17:17:32'
System info: host: 'blr2261913', ip: '10.177.101.114', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
Session ID: 71972154-3b97-4623-b651-aaa0bb460ffb
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, javascriptEnabled=true, elementScrollBehavior=0, ignoreZoomSetting=false, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=f
r=dismiss, version=11, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, requireWindowFocus=false, handlesAlerts=true,
e, browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, takesScreenshot=true}]
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.webdriven.SeleneseCommand.apply(SeleneseCommand.java:44)
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.webdriven.Timer.run(Timer.java:40)
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.webdriven.WebDriverCommandProcessor.execute(WebDriverCommandProcessor.java:143)
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.webdriven.WebDriverCommandProcessor.doCommand(WebDriverCommandProcessor.java:73)
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.type(DefaultSelenium.java:317)
```

**Env**: Windows7-64 bit, IE11
IEDriver version: Latest i.e 2.42.0
Selenium Server: 2.41.0

I have already followed the steps mentioned https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver ! NO LUCK!

Have searched enough over net but could not find any solution to my problem.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this applies directly to your problem but I have come across something similar when I got the error:

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

Which lead me to a bug raised here: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7077696

You have `recv failed` in your error similar to this bug, however it was noted that it's more likely to be Windows Firewall causing the error rather than a bug. Some possible workarounds (from the site):

- Run with `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`
- Add a firewall exception for the Java binary
- Or disable stateful FTP inspection in the firewall 
  which I believe is done with: `netsh advfirewall set global StatefulFTP disable`

There is also an issue raised here: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6437

Which applies to the error I have more so but it could possibly apply to yours? As comment #7 (from a project member) states there is a known issue with **IE11**.

This is may or may not help as I haven't had a chance to test the solutions and I'm not entirely sure of it myself!